# RPi as a NAT-router - low performance seen

Tags: networking

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 NAT+router setup and I am seeing that RPi-3 has a lower packet-forwarding performance than RPi-2.

wlan0 is set up with a DHCP server and a wifi-access point. eth0 is used as the connection to the Internet.

I have had a similar set up with RPi-2 before with an external USB-wifi adapter. RPi-3 has a built-in wifi interface and so I am using it.

For the similar setups, I thought RPi-2 used to get 10-12Mbps NAT+routing throughput (i.e. running Speedtest on a PC that connects to RPI's access point). Yesterday I created the RPi-3 setup, and Speedtest shows only 3Mbps throughput (consistent over multiple runs of speedtest).

Is this is a known difference in the performance of RPI-3 vs RPi-2? Or am I doing something wrong? When RPI-3 is not in the path, the client PC sees about 40Mbps throughput and so the bottleneck is certainly RPi-3. I would also suspect the hardware configuration first, but I find it hard to believe it could to worse than RPi-2.

[Link: A related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/performance-of-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-firewall) on this community - but that does not talk about the differences between these two hardware platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi3's On-board WiFi is known not to have good throughput.
https://netbeez.net/2016/06/01/iperf-wifi-comparison-on-raspberry-pi-raspberry-pi-3-vs-asus-vs-hawking-vs-linksys-vs-tp-link/

You may need USB WiFi dongle for performance purpose.